# How to get a specific HTML Tag from HTML page source by Attribute value

Tags: php, regex, xhtml, curl, html-parsing

I'm new at stackoverflow, hope find my solution here :)

Using PHP, i want a php function like:

```
function getHtmlTags($html_source, $tag='div', $by_attr="class", $attr_value="class_name"){
}
```

Ex: if 1 found, Should returns an array like so :

```
array([0] => '<div class="class_name">blah blah</div>');
```

I searched everywhere :( haven't found the solution! please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your HTML document into a [Document Object Model](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and use [XPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to find the element(s) based on the parameters given.

Regarding your regex tag - read this before descending into that nightmare - 
[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

For example (warning - completely untested)

```
/**
 * @return DOMNodeList
 */
function getHtmlTags($html_source, $tag='div', $by_attr="class", $attr_value="class_name")
{
    $document = new DOMDocument();
    if (!$document->loadHTML($html_source)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid HTML source');
    }

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $query = sprintf('//%s[%s="%s"]', $tag, $by_attr, $attr_value);

    return $xpath->query($query);
}
```

Comment: :D looks great to me, too much forward solution. thanks @PhilBrown